# Get unique string from a vector of similar strings

Tags: r, string, unique

I don't quite know how to phrase the question. I have just started to work on a bunch of tweets, I've done some basic cleaning and now some of the tweets look like:

```
x <- c("stackoverflow is a great site",
"stackoverflow is a great si",
"stackoverflow is a great",
"omg it is friday and so sunny",
"omg it is friday and so",
"arggh how annoying")
```

Basically I want to remove the repetitions by checking if the first parts of the strings match and return the longest of them. In this case my result should be:

```
[1]"stackoverflow is a great site"
[2]"omg it is friday and so sunny"
[3]"arggh how annoying"
```

because all the others are truncated repetitions of the above. I've tried using the 
`unique()` function but it doesn't return the results I want because it tries to match the whole length of the strings. Any pointers please?

I'm using R version 3.1.1 on Mac OSX 10.7...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is another option. I've added one string to your sample data.

```
x <- c("stackoverflow is a great site",
"stackoverflow is a great si",
"stackoverflow is a great",
"stackoverflow is an OK site",
"omg it is friday and so sunny",
"omg it is friday and so",
"arggh how annoying")

Filter(function(y) {
    x2 <- sapply(setdiff(x, y), substr, start=1, stop=nchar(y))
    ! duplicated(c(y, x2), fromLast=TRUE)[1]
}, x)


# [1] "stackoverflow is a great site" "stackoverflow is an OK site"   "omg it is friday and so sunny" [4] "arggh how annoying"
```

Comment: thanks Matthew I think it works fine it just looks very complicated I don't understand whats going on in there how do you get it to not treat `stackoverflow is a great site` and `stackoverflow is an OK site` as one? sorry thanks

Comment: I misunderstood your question. So you only want to match the first words?

Comment: no no no you've not misunderstood it works perfectly what i meant was how do you get it to differenciate between `stackoverflow is a great site` and `stackoverflow is an ok site?` just to have an idea whats going on in your code but it has solved the problem really

Comment: The idea is for each string, shrink all the other strings to the same length. If there are duplicates, then you know that a longer version of the current string exists, and you reject the current string. If there are no duplicates, then the current string is the longest, so you accept that one.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt:

```
library(stringr)
x[!sapply(seq_along(x), function(i) any(str_detect(x[-i], x[i])))]
[1] "stackoverflow is a great site" "omg it is friday and so sunny" "arggh how annoying"
```

Basically, I exclude those strings which are already included in any of the others. This is perhaps a bit different from what you describe, but does approximately the same and is quite simple.

Comment: thanks tony it seems to work but for shorter strings i my vector had about 1000 strings and it strip them down to 650. I don't think there's that much duplicates to strip but I'll have to check manually to get an idea

Comment: You can look at these duplicates by using `sort(x[sapply(seq_along(x), function(i) any(str_detect(x[-i], x[i])))])`.

Comment: looks like i have lots of duplicates you're right thanks this works and its cool to be able to see what it filters out thanks

Answer (score 1):

@tonytonov solution's is good, but i recommend to use [`stringi` package](http://stringi.rexamine.com) :)

```
stringi <- function(x){
  x[!sapply(seq_along(x), function(i) any(stri_detect_fixed(x[-i], x[i])))]
}

stringr <- function(x){
  x[!sapply(seq_along(x), function(i) any(str_detect(x[-i], x[i])))]
}

require(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(stringi(x), stringr(x))
Unit: microseconds
       expr     min       lq   median       uq      max neval
 stringi(x)  52.482  58.1760  64.3275  71.9630  120.374   100
 stringr(x) 538.482 551.0485 564.3445 602.7095 1736.601   100
```