# Identify truncated strings and expanding to longest string

Tags: r

Working with dirty data where many strings are truncated. Would like to create a new variable with the longest un-truncated string.

Example input:

```
x <- c("stackoverflow is a great site",
       "stackoverflow is a great si",
       "stackoverflow is a great",
       "stackoverflow is an OK site",
       "omg it is friday and so",
       "omg it is friday and so sunny",
       "arggh how annoying")
```

Desired output:

```
y <- c("stackoverflow is a great site",
       "stackoverflow is a great site",
       "stackoverflow is a great site",
       "stackoverflow is an OK site",
       "omg it is friday and so sunny",
       "omg it is friday and so sunny",
       "arggh how annoying")
```

After searching, the nearest I can find is this question\answer [Get unique string from a vector of similar strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25447296/get-unique-string-from-a-vector-of-similar-strings)

The various answers in that tread can identify the truncated and not truncated strings. example function:

```
mystringr <- function(x){
  x[!sapply(seq_along(x), function(i) any(str_detect(x[-i], x[i])))]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check for presence of each `x` in the remaining `x` and get the longest one.

```
sapply(x, function(s){
    temp = x[grepl(s, x)]
    temp[which.max(nchar(temp))]
},
USE.NAMES = FALSE)
#[1] "stackoverflow is a great site" "stackoverflow is a great site"
#[3] "stackoverflow is a great site" "stackoverflow is an OK site"  
#[5] "omg it is friday and so sunny" "omg it is friday and so sunny"
#[7] "arggh how annoying"
```

Comment: Thank you @d.b, I turned your answer into a function. Optimized by only searching the unique values. from 60sec to 13sec runtime. `fillIn2 <- function(x) {
  xDistinct<-unique(x);
  sapply(x, function(s) {
    temp = xDistinct[grepl(s, xDistinct)];
    temp[which.max(nchar(temp))];
  },
  USE.NAMES = FALSE)
}
`

Answer (score 1):

Using your mystringr function:

```
library(data.table)

#Given a single non-truncated string, get the original values which where truncated versions of it:
get_complete_str <- function(complete_str) {
  data.table(x) %>% 
    .[str_detect(complete_str, x)] %>% 
    .[, y := complete_str]
}

# Apply that function to every possible non-truncated string, and bind the result together:
lapply(mystringr(x), FUN = get_complete_str) %>% 
  rbindlist()
```